# как получить элемент из массива в котлине

Tags: java, kotlin

как получить элемент из

```
val a = arrayOf(
   intArrayOf(1, 1), intArrayOf(2, 26), intArrayOf(3, 44), intArrayOf(4, 60)
```

напр. первый стих 1 страница второй 26 стр и т.д.

Comment: Неужели в учебнике не написано?  

Answer (score 0):

Как и в любом другом си подобном языке программирования: `a[1][1]`, должно вернуть 26

Подробности [тут](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/kotlin-array/)